# Floating point arithmetic not working as expected

Tags: java, variables, math, double

The following simple floating point arithmetic operation is not working as expected.

```
double den = (1+j);
System.out.println(den);
den = 1/den;
System.out.println(den);

double newden = 1/(1+j);
System.out.println(newden);
```

The above code gives the following output.

> 7.0
>   0.14285714285714285
>   0.0

As shown above, the first two operations work as expected but the last doesn't. I suppose that it has something to do with the variable type but still haven't figured out the problem.

Can you please explain the behaviour of arithmetic operations in Java?

Comment: `1/(1+j)` is an `int` calculation and will leave you with an `int` result, while `1/den` is a `double` calculation (because `den` is a `double`), which will leave you with a `double`. (Just guessing for `j` beeing an `int` as it´s not visible what it represents here)

Comment: I guess j is an integer variable. So the whole expression `1/(1+j)` is threated to be an integer too. You can cast `j` to double to get the expected result. `newden = 1/(1+((double)j))`

Comment: ahhh got it `j` is just a counter. But why is `1/(1+j)` is an int calculation if I am declaring a double?

Comment: okay thanks! got it

Comment: @user3540466 because `1` is an `int` aswell as `j`, so the result of the calculation is an `int`, which will then be assigned to the `double`. The types of the calculation decides the output, not the type you are assigning to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An arithmetic operation in java is done in `int` if there is no `float/double/long` involved. Hence, change one of the arg to float/double and it works as expected.

The following code would work:

```
double newden = 1d/(i+j);
System.out.println(newden);
```

---

From the [java spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2):

> Widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2) is applied to convert either or
>   both operands as specified by the following rules, in order:
>
> - If either operand is of type double, the other is converted to double.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is of type float, the other is converted to float.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is of type long, the other is converted to long.
> - Otherwise, both operands are converted to type int.

Comment: why using floats when you want a double? You can simply use `1d/(1+j)`

Comment: @kaetzacoatl changed

Comment: Minor correcture: "The arithmetic operations in java is done in int if there is no float/double involved" - AND no `long`. This statement is then pretty accurate since every type < `int` is promoted to int. Even `byte + byte` will yield an `int`.

Comment: @Turing85 thanks for suggesting the change. updated the answer.

Comment: Please post text as text, and not as an image.  Also, the first point is misleading, and possibly wrong altogether;  an operation on two floats does not promote them and in fact returns a float, even if the unseen intermediate operation may convert the values to doubles under the hood.

Comment: @VGR updated with appropriate reference.

Answer (score 3):

This is working. If you try this by putting `(double) 1/(1+j);` there, you can see the result:

```
int j = 1;
        double den = (1+j);
        System.out.println(den);
        den = 1/den;
        System.out.println(den);

        double newden = (double) 1/(1+j);
        System.out.println(newden);
```

Here, 
your output will be:

```
2.0
0.5
0.5
```

Answer (score 2):

i guess j value is 6 so

`1/(1+6)`  will give you 0 considering `int` and assigning it to double convert it into `0.0`

Solution : cast any of value to `double`

```
double newden = (double)1/(1+j);
```

or

```
double newden = 1.0/(1+j);
```

or without casting

```
double newden =1;
newden /=(1+j);
```

[Read the awesome official doc about narrowing and Widening primitive conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html)